# FFMPEG. How to convert file with stereo (2 channels) to file with 8 channel (2 with sound + 6 mute)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, converters

I have a stereo video file which I would like to convert to another video file, but instead of only 2 channels I would like to have 8 audio channels. Two of them (1st and 2nd channel) would need to be the same as input file, all the rest has to be mute. I would like to use ffmpeg script. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-ac` option to change the number of channels. The extra channels will be mute.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -ac 8 output.mp4
```